# sudden high CPU, causing server to be unresponsive

Tags: apache-2.2, performance

I run a reasonably busy (700,000 page views/day, php/mysql) site that gets steady traffic (normally no spikes). The last two days, around peak usage time, and for about an hour, my site had suddenly gone from being very fast to unresponsive, for about an hour, and then back to being super fast.

The CPU load jumps dramatically at 2:10AM :

```
12:00:01 AM   runq-sz  plist-sz   ldavg-1   ldavg-5  ldavg-15
12:10:01 AM         1       270      2.54      3.56      4.00
12:20:01 AM        10       270      5.58      5.09      4.61
12:30:01 AM         9       297     10.06      9.63      7.22
12:40:01 AM         7       296      3.42      5.17      6.15
12:50:02 AM         8       291      4.36      4.57      5.43
01:00:02 AM        20       297      9.38      7.57      6.49
01:10:01 AM         6       279      5.83      6.86      6.90
01:20:01 AM        11       263      5.77      5.43      5.98
01:30:01 AM         2       291      6.70      5.56      5.66
01:40:01 AM         2       285      3.73      5.09      5.37
01:50:01 AM         6       285      3.84      4.65      5.11
02:00:01 AM         8       283      2.56      3.72      4.45
02:10:01 AM         2       431     14.67     10.88      7.34
02:20:01 AM         1       425      7.10     11.48      9.73
02:30:01 AM         4       453     10.30     12.79     11.23
02:40:01 AM         2       440     14.12     16.13     13.41
```

Here are my stats :

Hostgator VPS Level 7, 2 x 2GHz CPU, 3.2G RAM, CentOS 5.9, Apache 2.2.19, MySQL

- Mysql did not show any abnormal load during this time
- Apache was showing all workers in "W" state.
- Rebooting, restarting mysql, restarting apache all did not resolve the issue
- Nothing abnormal in apache error log (except lots of 503 errors during this time)

I'm really not sure where to start investigating this issue. I'd appreciate any pointers with :

1 - how to fully diagnose this issue now
2 - or what tools to install/ commands to run to capture extra data when it happens again.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked your logs?

Comment: Which log in particular ?

Comment: Sorry, I misread - didn't notice that apache was in a waiting state. This is a VPS, which means that you don't have dedicated hardware. Perhaps the underlying system were overloaded? Have you asked your provider?

Comment: Yes I asked the provider and they said there is no issue from their side (I don't fully believe them, but that's another story)

Comment: Do you have any cron jobs running at that time?

Comment: I do, but nothing significant.

Answer (score 2):

How to diagnose:
- Plot the graphs. Use munin, cacti or other external monitoring system to get to know, what exactly kind of resource has ended.
- Use atop or sar to get detailed information about processes activity in timeline. When you servers goes down, check dumps moving backward.

Comment: I have syssnap already installed, however it was not running. would this be useful or is munin/cati better ?

Comment: I agree with Paul. syssnap is a rather stoneage way to check server performance, and it doesn't give any lowlevel info except for which processes are running (as far as I can see). I have used both atop and munin, the first is good for checking momentary performance drops while the latter gives you a better oversight. With munin I routinely check disk/controller issues (because it does latency checks), network attacks/congestion and memory issues. As for your problem, I'd guess it could be that your apache has too few workers and/or forces your server to swap.

Answer (score 0):

Problem turned out to be a misbehaving cpanel system cron job that was using up all the CPU, in turn causing apache to be unable to serve requests.

Comment: And the lesson was learned… even if [the cron jobs look small](http://serverfault.com/questions/527245/sudden-high-cpu-causing-server-to-be-unresponsive#comment601934_527245), don't discount them. ;)